# How to merge all branches with the master branch?

Tags: git

I have a few branches locally and want to update them.
How to merge the stuff from master branch into all other branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

git checkout master
git pull

branches=()
eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format='branches+=(%(refname))' refs/heads/)"

for branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
   branch=`expr substr $branch 12 100`
   git checkout $branch
   git merge master
done

git checkout master
```

Comment: Ugh... I would replace that `eval ...` wart with `branches=( $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads) )`... And the `branch=...` bit with `branch=${branch//refs\/heads\//}`... Otherwise, I think that's about right...

Comment: You would also have the mother of all confusing situations if you had any merge conflicts at any of the steps.  And you can just use :short to the format specifier to get just the branch name.

Comment: @AndrewC That's a very good point in the general case. But if all you're doing is doing a `git fetch` followed by updating all your tracking branches to agree with `origin`, this sort of thing should be ok. But a big red warning flag on the script wouldn't be a bad idea. Also, I had forgotten about the `:short` modifier - thanks for the reminder...

Comment: he isn't updating the tracking braches to agree with origin, he's merging all his branches into master, and who knows what that entails.

Comment: @AndrewC No, the sequence `git checkout $branch; git merge master` merges `master` into each branch (which, admittedly is not the same thing as updating tracking branches, either)...

Comment: into/with - to-may-to/to-mah-to :) But yes, it doesn't matter what merge he is doing, unless it is a fast forward there can be conflicts.  That goes for an origin merge, or a branch to branch merge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you branched off of master:

```
git checkout my_branch
git rebase master
```

Comment: That's not right; the OP wants to *merge* `master` in `my_branch`, not *rebase* `my_branch` to `master`.

Comment: The OP seems to have a clear idea of what he wants and even posted a self-answer, which doesn't involve rebasing. I think your answer is off the mark.